# symonfy 1.4 Forms: Computed field and Validation

Tags: forms, validation, symfony-1.4

I have a doctrine-based-form, which I want augment with an additional field, lets call it `template`. Based on the value of `template` the other values should be altered.

I tried implementing this with a pre-validator, however this does not allow to alter values.

Using a post-validator is also not an option, since then the computed values (some are required) cannot be validated.

I know that I can just modify the values before `$form->bind($values)`, but I would appreciate a solution, that is integrated in the form-binding/validation process.

As a side note, I cannot use doUpdateObject or update%sColumn since the model represents a view and saving has to be done using a stored procedure with additional in-database integrity checks.

Answer (score 0):

Your validators are fine as they are as you know how they will clean your data.

I'd say you need to override the method *doUpdateObject* in your doctrine form [(doc)](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfFormDoctrine#method_doupdateobject),
since it's not real "data validation" but actual "data altering".

Comment: Thanks. I have thought about this, as well as using the `update%sColumn`-method. However in my case I don't save the data using doctrine, as this **has to be done** using a stored procedure.

The reason why I want(ed) to use a validator is that the post validator can transform the data, but I had to discover that the pre validator cannot.

Comment: Allright. This is more complex than I thought but can't you just call the public function *updateObject* that calls  *doUpdateObject* ? It will not save the data. Sorry if that suggestion is irrevelant but I have never used a model based on a view

Comment: Well this does work of course, but it makes no difference if I have to manually call `updateObject` or another non-API function. My thought was to somehow integrate this in the `$form->bind` process.

Comment: For the record: I did not find a properly integrated solution, so what I do now, I just set the new value based on `template`, and the call `$form->bind`.